# Spring Integration Exception

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am getting an exception in spring integration. Following is the snippet of my spring.xml file

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id=ïncomingFile" directory="file:${myapp.incomingFile.path}"prevent-duplicates="true"filename-regex="${filenameRegex}>

<int:poller id="poller"fixed-delay="5000"/>

</int-file:inbound-channeladapter>
```

Exception:

```
7 May 2014 13:52:17.903 [main] INFO  App.main - Starting with the main application
May 17, 2014 1:52:18 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@2814a18d: startup date [Sat May 17 13:52:18 EDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
May 17, 2014 1:52:18 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:./src/main/resources/spring//Spring-All-Module.xml]
May 17, 2014 1:52:18 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:src/main/resources/spring//filetracker.xml]
May 17, 2014 1:52:18 PM org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/sbhargava/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-integration-core-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring.integration.default.properties]
May 17, 2014 1:52:18 PM org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationRegistrar registerHeaderChannelRegistry
INFO: No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
May 17, 2014 1:52:18 PM org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from class path resource [config/filetracker.prop]
May 17, 2014 1:52:18 PM org.springframework.integration.config.DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor registerErrorChannel
INFO: No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
May 17, 2014 1:52:18 PM org.springframework.integration.config.DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor registerTaskScheduler
INFO: No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
May 17, 2014 1:52:18 PM org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/sbhargava/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-integration-core-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring.integration.default.properties]
May 17, 2014 1:52:18 PM org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ExecutorConfigurationSupport initialize
INFO: Initializing ExecutorService  'taskScheduler'
May 17, 2014 1:52:18 PM org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ExecutorConfigurationSupport shutdown
INFO: Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'incomingFiles.adapter': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'incomingFiles.adapter.source' while setting bean property 'source'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'incomingFiles.adapter.source': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/integration/MessagingException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:681)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.queryutility.jefferies.fileutility.App.main(App.java:28)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'incomingFiles.adapter.source': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/integration/MessagingException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:151)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:252)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:320)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/integration/MessagingException
    at org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.<init>(FileReadingMessageSource.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.<init>(FileReadingMessageSource.java:96)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.config.FileReadingMessageSourceFactoryBean.initSource(FileReadingMessageSourceFactoryBean.java:128)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.config.FileReadingMessageSourceFactoryBean.getObject(FileReadingMessageSourceFactoryBean.java:98)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.config.FileReadingMessageSourceFactoryBean.getObject(FileReadingMessageSourceFactoryBean.java:36)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:144)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.integration.MessagingException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 26 more
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MessagingException` has been moved to the `spring-messaging` module since Spring Framework 4.0 and Spring Integration 4.0.

If you see that exception, then you use an old version of some of Spring Integration modules. Might be ever `spring-integration-file`

Answer (score 0):

Use Same version for spring-integration-core and spring-integration-ftp or spring-integration-file will help. It worked for me.